# How to animate dataview items in sancha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am a newbie in sancha touch 2, Playing with kitchensink example that comes with sancha touch sdk                                                           `kitchensink/index.html#demo/inlinedataview`

UI for Inline Dataview

[image]

**View**

```
/* Here we are adding a dataview to a container
 * which(dataview) contains images.
 */ 
Ext.define('Kitchensink.view.InlineDataView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires: ['Kitchensink.model.Speaker'],
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'dataview',
            scrollable: true,
            inline: true,
            itemTpl: '<img src="{photo}">',
            store: 'Speakers'
        }]
    }
});
```

---

**Question**

I want to animate those images while they are being added to dataview in a way that they(each one of them individually) seems to fading in at a random place before showing the upper view.

Similar to **http://boedesign.com/demos/jsquares/**  `example1`

Sancha Doc Reference or A hint or how to do, will do it, but if you can paste some reference code that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I saw that no one replied to this in 8 months, and it still comes up in google:

so thought i provide a simple solution.

in your dataview override the doRefresh function

```
doRefresh: function ()
 {
 this.callParent(arguments);

 this.animateItems();
 },
```

then in your customer after-function (this.animateItems())

call:

```
var viewItems = this.getViewItems();
```

then roll some animations on them :)

i've created a plugin that attempts to simplify this.

hope it can help someone: http://sunnyjacob.co.uk/blog/animating-items-in-a-sencha-touch-dataview/

S.